# Does PyDict_SetItem increase the reference count of the key, and if so, where in the code does it take place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

TLDR: `PyDict_SetItem` increments the key and the value, but where in the code does this happen?

[PyDict_SetItem](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b55b65638254aa78b005fbf0b71fb02499f1852/Objects/dictobject.c#L1532) makes a call to `insertdict`.

[insertdict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b55b65638254aa78b005fbf0b71fb02499f1852/Objects/dictobject.c#L1036) immediately performs `Py_INCREF` on both the key and the value. However, at the [end of the success path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b55b65638254aa78b005fbf0b71fb02499f1852/Objects/dictobject.c#L1112), it then does a `Py_DECREF` on the key, (but not the value). There must be some part of this code that I am missing where it does an extra `PY_INCREF` on the key, before it does this `PY_DECREF`. **My question is where and why does this extra PY_INCREF take place?** Why is the initial `Py_INCREF` at the start of `insertdict` insufficient?

From this, it seems at first glance that `PyDict_SetItem` only increases the reference count of the value, but not the key. This is not true, of course. For example, in [PyDict_SetItemString](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1b55b65638254aa78b005fbf0b71fb02499f1852/Objects/dictobject.c#L3409), which takes a `char *`, converts it into a PyObject via `PyUnicode_FromString` (which returns a new value), performs a `Py_DECREF` on that new value after calling `PyDict_SetItem`. If `PyDict_SetItem` does not increment the key, and `PyDict_SetItemString` decrements the key it just created, the program may eventually segfault. Given that doesn't happen, it seems like I am missing something here.

---

Finally, this code should prove that `PyDict_SetItem` increments both the key and the value, and that the caller should decref both the key and value unless they were borrowed references/ or will give the key and values to someone else.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *dict = NULL, *key = NULL, *value = NULL;
    int i = 5000;
    char *o = "foo";

    if (!(dict = PyDict_New())) {
        goto error;
    }
    if (!(key = Py_BuildValue("i", i))) {
        goto error;
    }
    if (!(value = Py_BuildValue("s", o))) {
        goto error;
    }
    printf("Before PyDict_SetItem\n");
    printf("key is %i\n", key->ob_refcnt);  /* Prints 1 */
    printf("value is %i\n", value->ob_refcnt);  /* Prints 1 */

    printf("Calling PyDict_SetItem\n");
    if (PyDict_SetItem(dict, key, value) < 0) {
        goto error;
    }
    printf("key is %i\n", key->ob_refcnt);  /* Prints 2 */
    printf("value is %i\n", value->ob_refcnt);  /* Prints 2 */

    printf("Decrefing key and value\n");
    Py_DECREF(key);
    Py_DECREF(value);
    printf("key is %i\n", key->ob_refcnt);   /* Prints 1 */
    printf("value is %i\n", value->ob_refcnt);   /* Prints 1 */

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0; // would return the dict in normal code
error:
    printf("error");
    Py_XDECREF(dict);
    Py_XDECREF(key);
    Py_XDECREF(value);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 1;
}
```

You can compile like:

```
gcc -c -I/path/to/python/include/python3.7m dict.c
gcc dict.o -L/path/to/python/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-i386-linux-gnu -L/path/to/python/lib -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/python/lib -lpython3.7m -lpthread -lm -ldl -lutil -lrt -Xlinker -export-dynamic -m32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Py_DECREF(key);` in `insertdict` doesn't happen for all successes. It happens on a success *when an equal key was already present*, either because there was an existing entry or because the dict was a split-table dict sharing keys with other dicts that had that key. On that path, the provided key isn't inserted, so the original `Py_INCREF(key);` needs to be canceled.

On the key-not-present path, `insertdict` hits a [different `return` statement](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Objects/dictobject.c#L1084) and doesn't decref the key:

```c
if (ix == DKIX_EMPTY) {
    /* Insert into new slot. */
    assert(old_value == NULL);
    if (mp->ma_keys->dk_usable <= 0) {
        /* Need to resize. */
        if (insertion_resize(mp) < 0)
            goto Fail;
    }
    Py_ssize_t hashpos = find_empty_slot(mp->ma_keys, hash);
    ep = &DK_ENTRIES(mp->ma_keys)[mp->ma_keys->dk_nentries];
    dictkeys_set_index(mp->ma_keys, hashpos, mp->ma_keys->dk_nentries);
    ep->me_key = key;
    ep->me_hash = hash;
    if (mp->ma_values) {
        assert (mp->ma_values[mp->ma_keys->dk_nentries] == NULL);
        mp->ma_values[mp->ma_keys->dk_nentries] = value;
    }
    else {
        ep->me_value = value;
    }
    mp->ma_used++;
    mp->ma_version_tag = DICT_NEXT_VERSION();
    mp->ma_keys->dk_usable--;
    mp->ma_keys->dk_nentries++;
    assert(mp->ma_keys->dk_usable >= 0);
    ASSERT_CONSISTENT(mp);
    return 0;
}
```